# How to morph two grid-like images seamlessly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, morphing

I have two images that consist of colored squares with different grid step (10x10 and 12x12).

What I want is to make the first image to be smoothly transformed into the second one.

[image: 10x10 grid-like image]
[image: 12x12 grid-like image]

When I use a plain image overlay with [cv2.addWeighted()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html) function, the result (left) is not good because of the intersected grid spaces. I suppose it would be better to shift remaining grid cells to the borders and clear out the rest (right).

[image: The weighted average of two grid-like images]
[image: The desired result of two grid-like images]

Is there any algorithm to deal with this task?

Thanks.

Comment: and how are these pictures related? what do you imagine/desire to happen?

Comment: You can interpolate from left image to right image with https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html

Comment: "shouldn't look like" still doesn't narrow down how it _should_ look like. you're talking about an entire animation of multiple frames. there's several ways I can imagine "morphing" this...

Comment: What do you mean by "transformed into the second one"? If you want the first one to look like the second one, just replace all the pixel values. If you want some kind of matching, stitching or blending I dont see how both images fit together.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see it directly, but the grid resolution is different, right (NxN pixels per cell vs. MxM pixels per cell?)? I think you should find a representatiion where the grid cells are already aligned before working on both images at the same time.

Comment: @jkhadka, thanks. Can you clarify how to use splrep there? In docs, it's explained how to make points interpolation but here we have 2D-images and not plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpolate each pixel individually between different images.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(200)

num_images = 2
images = np.random.rand(num_images, 8,8)

for index, im in enumerate(images):
    print(f'Images {index}')
    fig = plt.imshow(im)
    plt.show()
```

[image: Initial images]

Interpolating these images:

```py
n_frames = 4
x_array = np.linspace(0, 1, int(n_frames))


def interpolate_images(frame):
    intermediate_image = np.zeros((1, *images.shape[1:]))
    for lay in range(images.shape[1]):
        for lat in range(images.shape[2]):
            tck = interpolate.splrep(np.linspace(0, 1, images.shape[0]), images[:, lay, lat], k = 1)
            intermediate_image[:, lay, lat] = interpolate.splev(x_array[frame], tck)
    return intermediate_image


for frame in range(n_frames):
    im = interpolate_images(int(frame))
    fig = plt.imshow(im[0])
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So is this basically a cross-fade between the two?